# Expectation of Multidimensional Function of Random Variables w.r.t. Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Suppose two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are given. $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ will be the uncentered covariance of them. But this expectation is with respect to the joint distribution $P(X,Y)$. My question is what is the expectation if we take the expectation w.r.t say $Y$, i.e. something like
$$
\mathbb{E}_Y(XY)= \int XY dP(Y)
$$
I first thought $X$ will come out of the integral so that we would get:
$$
\mathbb{E}_Y(XY)= X\int Y dP(Y)
$$
but I realized that doesn't make sense since if say $Y=X$ this would be a wrong equation and we actually end up getting $\int Y^2 dP(y)$ which is a number. So now my question is whether
$$\int f(X,Y)dP(y)$$
is well-defined or not, and if not, why it is in the special case of $X=Y$?

**EDITED QUESTION**(Thanks to @kimchilover)

Answer (score 1):

This is so mixed up.  The conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$ is a  function of $Y$, call it $g(Y)$ (a.k.a. $g(Y)=E(X|Y)$)  such that $E( Xf(Y)) = E (g(Y)f(Y))$ for every function $f$. (That is, such that all  the law of iterated expectations holds every-which way.) (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) for more info.)

If you know $E(XY)$ you can use this formula to write $E(XY)=E( E(X|Y)Y)$ with $g(Y)=E(X|Y)$ and $f(Y)=Y$.

That's it.  But of course there are many notational variations possible. One is: $$ E XY = \int E(X|Y=y)yP(dy).$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am very confused too. What I am wondering is that either $\int f(X,Y)dP(y)$ is well-defined or not. And if not, why not?

Comment: I have changed my answer slightly.  It is still not clear to me if your question is about the measure-theoretic *meaning* of conditional expectation or if it is about the *notations* used for conditional expectation.

Comment: sorry for my late getback. Thanks a lot! My question is mostly about the measure theoretic problem as I phrased it in the comment. Maybe I need to change my question to reflect that.